# Async.js queue worker not finishing

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, typescript, async.js

A job queue for performing a copy operation using robocopy is established using the code below:

```
interface copyProcessReturn {
    jobId: number,
    code: number,
    description: string,
    params: string[],
    source: string,
    target: string,
    jobsLeft: number
}

export default class CopyHandler {
 private aQueue: AsyncQueue<copyProcess>;

 constructor() {
    let that = this;
    this.aQueue = async.queue(function (cp: copyProcess) {
        that.performCopy(cp);
        that.copy_complete();
    }, 1);     
 }

 private copy_complete() {
     // NOP
 }  

 public addCopyProcess(cp: copyProcess): void {
    this.aQueue.push(cp);
 }
```

The aim is to enable the execution of one copy process at a time while maintaining concurrency in terms of adding additional copy processes to the queue.

This works fine for the first job and additional jobs get queued correctly. However, even though the copy_complete() callback is called correctly once a job is finished, its worker is not freed and additional jobs in the queue remain unprocessed.

I'd be very thankful for hints.

Comment: The function in async.queue has 2 arguments second being callback that you need to call after that.copy_complete(); to let async library know that it has finished and it can run next fn in queue

Comment: Thanks, the async.worker now finishes as intended. If you post your comment as answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Cool, i will do i was on the phone so it was easier to comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in async.queue has 2 arguments second being callback function that you need to call after `that.copy_complete();` to let async library know that it has finished and it can run next fn in queue. Something like:

```
this.aQueue = async.queue(function (cp, next) {
    that.performCopy(cp);
    that.copy_complete();
    next();
}, 1);
```